# Datarow isn't finding the row from the table - results in object reference not set to the instance of an object

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to locate a filed in my database table. I done this successfully with tables that just required one key to find, however this table has a composite key attached to it so I have to use the following code to pass in the two keys

```
                //Saving quantity edits
                // Create an array for the key values to find. 
                object[] findTheseVals = new object[2];

                // Set the values of the keys to find.
                findTheseVals[0] = int.Parse(cbo_OrderID.Text);
                findTheseVals[1] = int.Parse(txt_orderitemIDtext.Text);

                drOrderEdit = dsOrderItem.Tables["OrderItem"].Rows.Find(findTheseVals);
```

It accepts the two keys as i am no longer getting an error saying something along the lines of 'expecting two keys only received one' the crash happens at the next line of code where I get an 'object is not set to an instance of an object' error

```
                //Error is at this begin edit statement
                drOrderEdit.BeginEdit();
                drOrderEdit["Quantity"] = txt_editquantity.Text;
                drOrderEdit.EndEdit();
                daEditOrderItem.Update(dsOrderItem, "OrderItem");
```

Why isn't the Datarow being set? the two values that are assigned to the object array are values that that are contained in the primary key and composite key columns.

Here's the script for the creation of the table concerned:

```
Create Table OrderItem
(
    OrderItemID int not null,
    OrderID int  not null,
    Quantity smallint not null,
    ProductID INT not null, 
    CHECK (Quantity > 0 AND Quantity < 51),
    CONSTRAINT PK_OIOrderID PRIMARY KEY (OrderID,ProductID),
     CONSTRAINT FK_Prod FOREIGN KEY (ProductID)
        REFERENCES Product(ProductID)
            on delete cascade,
        CONSTRAINT FK_Order foreign key (OrderID) 
                    REFERENCES ORDERS (OrderID)
                            on delete cascade
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like my script was set up incorrectly.

The line

```
CONSTRAINT PK_OIOrderID PRIMARY KEY (OrderID,ProductID),
```

Should have been

```
CONSTRAINT PK_OIOrderID PRIMARY KEY (OrderItemID,OrderID),
```

Made these changes, and the edits were accepted.